# What does "radar detection" mean?

Tags: wifi, iwlwifi, iw

When I run `sudo iw phy`, I get,

```
5500 MHz [100] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
5520 MHz [104] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
5540 MHz [108] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
5560 MHz [112] (22.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
```

What does *radar detection* mean in that context?

Comment: You may be interested in [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1868719#p1868719).